# How to add item to json object ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, rendering

I want to join items from 2 tables. There output:

```
 "costs":[  
  {  
     "id":2,
     "cost_name":"rent office",
     "user_id":2,
     "fix":true,
     "amount":300300,
     "created_at":"2018-11-05T18:36:19.108+06:00",
     "updated_at":"2018-11-05T18:36:19.108+06:00"
  },
  {  
     "id":3,
     "cost_name":"new computer",
     "user_id":2,
     "fix":false,
     "amount":350000,
     "created_at":"2018-11-06T14:44:49.805+06:00",
     "updated_at":"2018-11-06T14:44:49.805+06:00"
  }


 ],
   "users":[  
      [  
         "Vi_Ok",
         2
      ]
   ]
}
```

I want to add parameter of users (user name which is "Vi_Ok") add to every cost. How you noticed there in both table exist userId. Now code looks:

```
def index
@costs = Cost.all 
@user_name = @costs.pluck(:user_id)
@user_name = User.find(@user_name).pluck(:name, :id)
# @costs.push("name" => @user_name.pluck(:name) this one just try to add 
render json: {costs: @costs, name: @user_name}
```

end

Comment: user is unique to all costs or different to each cost?

Comment: @UdAY Yea, it looks so.

Comment: What is association between cost and user ?

Comment: @ray with the data provided it looks so. What if user varies with cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom method in your model and call it in index action, which returns all the costs with the username like below:

```
def self.list_costs
  cost_list = []
  costs = Cost.all
  costs.each do |cost|
    cost_info = cost.attributes
    cost_info[:user_name] = cost.user.name
    cost_list << cost_info
  end
  cost_list
end  

class CostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: {costs: Cost.cost_list }
  end
end
```

Comment: It is proper approach

Comment: After changing: {costs: Cost.cost_list }    to     {costs: Cost.list_cost } 

and changing:  cost_info[:user_name] = cost.user.name    to  st_info[:user_name] = User.find(cost.user_id).name
all start to work thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Supposing User has_many Costs,

What you provided,

```
hash =  {"costs"=>[{"id"=>2, "cost_name"=>"rent office", "user_id"=>2, "fix"=>true, "amount"=>300300, "created_at"=>"2018-11-05T18:36:19.108+06:00", "updated_at"=>"2018-11-05T18:36:19.108+06:00"}, {"id"=>3, "cost_name"=>"new computer", "user_id"=>2, "fix"=>false, "amount"=>350000, "created_at"=>"2018-11-06T14:44:49.805+06:00", "updated_at"=>"2018-11-06T14:44:49.805+06:00"}], "users"=>[["Vi_Ok", 2]]}
```

Proceed,

```
costs, users = hash['costs'], hash['users']
costs.each { |c| c['user_name'] = users.detect { |u| u[1] == c['user_id'] }[0] }
```

Above will add `user_name` in each cost hash.